# Buffer overflow: writing code to stack and executing there

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, exploit

I know what a buffer overflow is and I know that (without DEP), often stack return addresses are overwritten with an address pointing somewhere in data or code sections.. but what if the stack return address were overwritten with another stack address overwritten with executable code? Would DEP be still effective in that case? "Data Execution prevention" sounds like only the "Data" section is effectively protected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DEP prevents execution of code on the stack, as well as the heap. In other words, the stack is viewed as being *data*.